# Intentionally duplicated step

Tags: getgauge

For one scenario that I'm writing, I have two different steps that do the same action:

```
* Click "R$ "
```

However, when running gauge an error shows up:

```
Failed Step: Click "R$ "
        Specification: specs/example.spec:10
        Error Message: Error: Element matching text "R$ " is covered by other element
        Stacktrace: 
        Error: Element matching text "R$ " is covered by other element
            at _click (node_modules/taiko/lib/taiko.js:715:15)
```

**How can I intentionally add a duplicate step?**

Here's my full scenario:

```
* Login at "localhost:8001", as "user" and password "pass"
* Goto "localhost:8004/page/status"
* Check if text "Status page" exists on page
* Click "R$ "
* Check if text "Edit status" exists on page
* Click "R$ "
* Change value to "5"
```

The `* Click "R$ "` implementation is (same as [source](https://github.com/getgauge-examples/js-taiko/blob/master/tests/click.js)):

```
step("Click <selector>", async function(selector) {
    await click(selector);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate steps are allowed in gauge. But the error you are facing is from taiko. So please check if the element you are trying to click is covered by any other element.